# Is GCP Cloud function eventId sequential?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#function_parameters
Following the documentation, is says that the parameter `context.eventId` is a unique ID for the event. For example: "70172329041928".

My question is, is this event sequential? Would an event that happens later in time always have a higher event_id than an earlier event?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the documentation states that the value is a timestamp, do not try to use it as one. It is a unique number, use it for only that purpose.